# Creating an image from a dictionary using PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a dictionary that maps coordinate tuples (in the range (0,0) to (199, 199) to grayscale values (integers between 0 and 255.) Is there a good way to create an PIL Image that has the specified values at the specified coordinates? I'd prefer a solution that only uses PIL to one that uses scipy.

Comment: Is every possible coordinate tuple represented? If not, what's the background value?

Comment: The background value would be 255 in this case, but but it might be 0 in another case.

Comment: So I take it that every possible coordinate tuple isn't represented in the dictionary, correct?

Comment: Correct (although the dictionary could be constructed to contain the default background value at every other point.)

Comment: It would generally be much faster to define it outside the dictionary, especially if using `putpixel()` to create the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As martineau suggests `putpixel()` is ok when you're modifying a few random pixels, but it's not so efficient for building whole images. My approach is similar to his, except I use a list of ints and `.putdata()`. Here's some code to test these 3 different approaches.

```
from PIL import Image
from random import seed, randint

width, height = 200, 200
background = 0

seed(42)
d = dict(((x, y), randint(0, 255)) for x in range(width) for y in range(height))

algorithm = 2
print('Algorithm', algorithm)

if algorithm == 0:
    im = Image.new('L', (width, height))
    for i in d:
        im.putpixel(i, d[i])
elif algorithm == 1:
    buff = bytearray((background for _ in xrange(width * height)))
    for (x,y), v in d.items():
        buff[y*width + x] = v
    im = Image.frombytes('L', (width,height), str(buff))
elif algorithm == 2:
    data = [background] * width * height
    for i in d:
        x, y = i
        data[x + y * width] = d[i]
    im = Image.new('L', (width, height))
    im.putdata(data)

#im.show()

fname = 'qrand%d.png' % algorithm
im.save(fname)
print(fname, 'saved')
```

Here are typical timings on my 2GHz machine running Python 2.6.6

```
$ time ./qtest.py
Algorithm 0
qrand0.png saved

real    0m0.926s
user    0m0.768s
sys     0m0.040s

$ time ./qtest.py
Algorithm 1
qrand1.png saved

real    0m0.733s
user    0m0.548s
sys     0m0.020s

$ time ./qtest.py
Algorithm 2
qrand2.png saved

real    0m0.638s
user    0m0.520s
sys     0m0.032s
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to include my own benchmark of all the current answers. Your approach is indeed a bit faster than mine, +1.

Comment: Accepted since this is the one I used. I like only updating an image once.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [`image.putpixel()`](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.putpixel) to change the color of a pixel at a particular position. Example code -

```
from PIL import Image
from random import randint

d = {(x,y):randint(0,255) for x in range(200) for y in range(200)}
im = Image.new('L',(200,200))

for i in d:
    im.putpixel(i,d[i])

im.save('blah.png')
```

It gave me a result like -

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This definitely works, although I ended up going with an answer that only modifies images once.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with `putpixel()`, but that could potentially involve tens of thousands of calls. How much this matters depends on how many coordinate tuples are defined in the dictionary. I've included the method shown in each of the current answers for comparison (including my own before any benchmarking was added, but just now I made a small change to how it initializes the data buffer which measurably sped it up).

To make a level playing field, for testing purposes the input dictionary randomly selects only ½ of the possible pixels in the image to define and allows the rest to be set to a default `background` color. Anand S Kumar's answer currently doesn't do the latter, but the slightly modified version shown below does.

All produce the same image from the data.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
from textwrap import dedent
import timeit

N = 100  # number of executions of each algorithm
R = 3  # number of repeations of executions

# common setup for all algorithms - is not included in algorithm timing
setup = dedent("""
    from random import randint, sample, seed
    from PIL import Image

    seed(42)
    background = 0  # default color of pixels not defined in dictionary
    width, height = 200, 200

    # create test dict of input data defining half of the pixel coords in image
    coords = sample([(x,y) for x in xrange(width) for y in xrange(height)],
                    width * height // 2)
    d = {coord: randint(0, 255) for coord in coords}
""")

algorithms = {
    "Anand S Kumar": dedent("""
        im = Image.new('L', (width, height), color=background)  # set bgrd
        for i in d:
            im.putpixel(i, d[i])
    """),

    "martineau": dedent("""
        data = bytearray([background] * width * height)
        for (x, y), v in d.iteritems():
            data[x + y*width] = v
        im = Image.frombytes('L', (width, height), str(data))
    """),

    "PM 2Ring": dedent("""
        data = [background] * width * height
        for i in d:
            x, y = i
            data[x + y * width] = d[i]
        im = Image.new('L', (width, height))
        im.putdata(data)
    """),
}

# execute and time algorithms, collecting results
timings = [
    (label,
     min(timeit.repeat(algorithms[label], setup=setup, repeat=R, number=N)),
    ) for label in algorithms
]

print('fastest to slowest execution speeds (Python {}.{}.{})\n'.format(
        *sys.version_info[:3]),
        '  ({:,d} executions, best of {:d} repetitions)\n'.format(N, R))
longest = max(len(timing[0]) for timing in timings)  # length of longest label
ranked = sorted(timings, key=lambda t: t[1])  # ascending sort by execution time
fastest = ranked[0][1]
for timing in ranked:
    print("{:>{width}} : {:9.6f} secs, rel speed {:4.2f}x, {:6.2f}% slower".
            format(timing[0], timing[1], round(timing[1]/fastest, 2),
                   round((timing[1]/fastest - 1) * 100, 2), width=longest))
```

Output:

```
fastest to slowest execution speeds (Python 2.7.10)
   (100 executions, best of 3 repetitions)

    martineau :  0.255203 secs, rel speed 1.00x,   0.00% slower
     PM 2Ring :  0.307024 secs, rel speed 1.20x,  20.31% slower
Anand S Kumar :  1.835997 secs, rel speed 7.19x, 619.43% slower
```

Comment: Thanks for the very impressive benchmarking! I accepted PM 2ring's answer since I used his technique, but a virtual +1 for you (since I don't have enough rep to vote up yet.)

Comment: You're welcome. The benchmarking framework itself is useful to keep around since it can fairly easily be adapted to determine the relative execution speed of almost any snippets of code in a platform independent way.

Comment: Thanks, martineau. I was feeling too lazy to do timeit tests. :) But it's definitely a good idea when the setup phase takes a significant proportion of the total execution time.

Comment: @MaxRosett: You have enough rep to vote now. :) And enough rep to use the SO Chat rooms. You guys should check out [SO Python](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) some time.

Comment: @PM 2Ring: Couldn't agree more. `;-)`